# Stuck mapping location heatmap on python

Tags: python, geopandas, folium, geopy

I am working on an exercise which consists on retrieving data from foursquare in order to determine where to add a Gym based on less competition.
I have already called the API and cleaned my data, and was even able to map all the gyms.
I am stuck, however in figuring out a way to use the data (coordinates) from my set, with the restriction that it needs to be limited to a specific area (I figured I can do top-left, right bottom coordinates for this).
Any ideas?

[picture of my current map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVsNU.png)

A solution using heat maps instead of an exact location would work as well.

Comment: Please, refine your question with a clear goal. Furthermore, please provide full code and data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean distance xor Manhattan distance could be triangulation based pattern recognition derived of knneighbor alg.

- I would suggest looking into linking and chaining locations and applying a knn based algorithm compatible to the api call for optimal dist, and further develop derived metas from the bases.
- some immediate thoughts came to me as I had to complete a very similar project in 10 days.

:initial_thoughts ~

> .__o(N1?)=rnt?

[.get, .describe, .info, .shape, .round, .map, **warm_start**(condition)=T/F, geopandas, **pyautogui**, **pyautoui**, .describe, .dist, .metrics, .values, *(also, is this **linear** or nonlinear based? Some discretionary values can be calculated from *bootstrapping* **ceiling floor differentials** :: **partial differentials** for aprx dist.

Take a look into different density, even `theta per area*dens, Kp) / sensitivity * time(req)` ,..., and **foot.traffic** functions that are available. **py 3.8** was best for this based on *mapping properties*.